# Proving inequalities, equations including limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $t_n=\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n}}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
>
> **1)** show that $\sqrt{n}=t^n_{n}=((t_n-1)+1)^n\geq1+n(t_n-1)$

Let $x\geq0$

$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\binom{n}{2}x^2+...+x^n\geq1+nx$$

Suppose $t_n<1$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

> **2)** Show that $0\leq t_n-1\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and show that $t_n\rightarrow 1$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$

Im thinking I need to show that $t_n-1$ and $\sqrt{n}$ are defined by something, from (1). Not certain if I could do it without finishing (1).

> **3)** $\sqrt[n]{n}=t^2_{n}\rightarrow 1$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$

Here I need the fact that the limit of $t_n=1$. And then I could do the following.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}$$
$$=>\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n^2$$
$$=>(\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n)(\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n)$$
$$=>(1)(1)=1$$

---

Any hints would be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand how $t_n$ is defined.

Comment: My bad, i forgot to add it! $t_n=\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n}}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: what is your question

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is a bit confused. That's what I understood.

You have a sequence $t_n=n^{\frac{1}{2n}}$ and you have to find the limit as $n\to\infty$

Take $$\log\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\log n^{\frac{1}{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\frac{\log n}{2n}=^{L'Hopital}\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{2}=0$$

If $\log\lim\,t_n=1$ then $\lim\, t_n=e^0=1$

that is also the limit of $\sqrt[n]{n}$

Hope this helps

Comment: I think I've misunderstood parts or all of the task. But we havn't learnt L'Hopital yet, so that might not be what this task is designed to learn/practice

Answer (score 1):

As $$n>1$$ so is also $$t_n=\sqrt[2n]n>1.$$ Thus you get 1) by your previous considerations. Then from 1) follows
$$
\sqrt n\ge 1+n(t_n-1)\iff t_n-1\le \frac1{\sqrt n}-\frac1n
$$
and from there you get the convergence.